# PayPal transaction issue with DoDirectPayment method

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created two test accounts(buyer and seller) in PayPal sandbox. And then trying to transfer money via my simple webapp. I'm using DoDirectPayment method for sending money. Method returns following result:

`Direct Payment Completed Successfully: Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2012%2d07%2d30T17%3a27%3a38Z [CORRELATIONID] => 83da0b009d36d [ACK] => Success [VERSION] => 92%2e0 [BUILD] => 3288089 [AMT] => 10%2e00 [CURRENCYCODE] => USD [AVSCODE] => X [CVV2MATCH] => M [TRANSACTIONID] => 0MJ25519PP687260E )` 

Transaction completed successfully, but I got problem with test accounts money.
I transferred 10.00 USD from account with 1000.00 USD, but buyer account sum didn't change.
So seller gets his 10.00 USD and his sum is (200.00 USD + 10.00 USD - fee).
When I'm logging in as seller I can see transaction history with transfer actions.
But when I'm logging in as buyer transaction history is empty.

For checking transaction details, I used GetTransactionDetails method. Here it's result: 

`GetTransactionDetails Completed Successfully: Array ( [RECEIVERBUSINESS] => lukina_1343245948_biz%40gmail%2ecom [RECEIVEREMAIL] => lukina_1343245948_biz%40gmail%2ecom [RECEIVERID] => 7YKBZRV887SUC [PAYERID] => AJPWLMQCND7SG [PAYERSTATUS] => unverified [COUNTRYCODE] => US [ADDRESSOWNER] => PayPal [ADDRESSSTATUS] => None [SALESTAX] => 0%2e00 [SHIPAMOUNT] => 0%2e00 [SHIPHANDLEAMOUNT] => 0%2e00 [TIMESTAMP] => 2012%2d07%2d30T17%3a27%3a40Z [CORRELATIONID] => 56291b407d388 [ACK] => Success [VERSION] => 92%2e0 [BUILD] => 3386080 [FIRSTNAME] => Joe [LASTNAME] => Bell [TRANSACTIONID] => 0MJ25519PP687260E [RECEIPTID] => 3093%2d6316%2d6806%2d7055 [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => webaccept [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant [ORDERTIME] => 2012%2d07%2d30T17%3a27%3a37Z [AMT] => 10%2e00 [FEEAMT] => 0%2e59 [TAXAMT] => 0%2e00 [CURRENCYCODE] => USD [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed [PENDINGREASON] => None [REASONCODE] => None [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None [L_QTY0] => 1 [L_TAXAMT0] => 0%2e00 [L_CURRENCYCODE0] => USD )` 


Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sandbox mode with the buyer's account does not withdraw the money in transaction. It is solve of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the `DoDirectPayment` API you're charging a credit card directly. Even if this credit card happens to be attached to an active PayPal account, it will not show up on that account's transaction history.

This is by design. If you wish to charge someone's PayPal account (and thus not a credit card directly), you would use [PayPal Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/express-checkout).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my main trouble is not in it.